# .htaccess password protection deny from request uri

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, password-protection

I want to request uri /admin then `.htacccess` protected password `answer` then allow from /admin

This code is not working

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin require_auth=false
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Staging Server"
AuthUserFile /system/pw/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Deny from env=require_auth
Satisfy any
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#allows a single uri through the .htaccess password protection
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/admin" test_uri
#allows everything if its on a certain host
Order Deny,Allow
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /system/pw/.htpasswd
#Allow valid-user
Deny from env=test_uri
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Where does this go if the htaccess file has other URL  rewriting rules?